# NullPointerexception in getting session

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting the following exception.Its due to the line

```
Session  ss=session.getCurrentSession();

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mkyong.common.dao.UserDao.saveUser(UserDao.java:25)
    at com.mkyong.common.controller.JSONController.getShopInJSON(JSONController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My dao class is as follows.

```
 package com.mkyong.common.dao;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.mkyong.common.model.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public class UserDao {

    private SessionFactory session;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory session){
        if(session == null){
         throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        this.session=session;
    }


    public int saveUser(User user) {

        Session  ss=session.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println(user.getUserName());
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        //Session ss=session.getCurrentSession();
        ss.save(user);



        return 1; 



}


}
```

My config file is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

        <mvc:annotation-driven />





    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mkyong.common.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean> 


</beans>
```

Comment: My dao clas is as follows.

Comment: Can you post the code here ? It seems your session is `null` !!!

Comment: How are you `injecting` your session ? Your config file please !!!

Comment: do you have a trasaction manager

Comment: hwo are you creating the dao bean?

Comment: I have posted my Spring config file.

Comment: Isn't it be `@AutoWired private SessionFactory session;` ?

Comment: I did that but same error came.

Comment: How are you creating the `UserDao` bean ?

Comment: I am using <bean id="userDAO" class="com.mkyong.common.dao.UserDAO">
    <property name="session" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>

Answer (score 0):

Your `session` is null.You are using `getCurrentSession` on  `null` .So you are getting NullpointeException here

Answer (score 0):

Your session is not injected in your DAO. Ensure your configuration is correct.

You can inject your session factory in two ways (choose just one)

1) Xml declaration
Here you will declare your userDAO bean in your xml configuration file this way :

```
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.mkyong.common.dao.UserDAO">
    <property name="session" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I sometimes have issue when the id of my bean start with a Uppercase letter, so I would rename "SessionFactory" by "sessionFactory".

2) With annotations

Here, Spring will scan all packages declared with

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />
```

and look for Classes annotated with "@Repository", "@Service" or "@Component" in com.foo.bar package. So, Your class UserDAO should be annotated with "@Repository" to be found and your package must be in component-scan to be scanned.
Now Spring will detect your userDAO bean but don't see any bean to inject, so you must annotate your SessionFactory field with "@Autowired", your class must look like this :

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory session;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory session){
    if(session == null){
     throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    this.session=session;
}

...
```

And your configuration file look like this :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.dao" />
<context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

...

</beans>
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception after adding bean  Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' for property 'Session'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] for property 'Session': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: My bad. Use <property name="session" ref="SessionFactory" /> instead of <property name="session" value="SessionFactory" />

Comment: Same null pointer exception  is coming.I have given <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.conroller" /> instead of <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.dao" />.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you use xml declaration or annotation configuration ?

Comment: I have did all the changes that were suggested in this post.But still I am getting the same error.Could you please tell me what to do next.

Comment: You must choose between 1) xml declaration and add the declaration <bean id="userDAO" class="com.mkyong.common.dao.UserDAO">
    <property name="session" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean> WITHOUT using component-scan OR 2) annotation configuration WITHOUT adding the userDAO in your configuration file, instead add the "@Repository" and "@Autowired" annotations AND use the following package in component-scan : com.mkyong.common.dao

Comment: I have removed bean from configuration file and added like this @Repository public class UserDao

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it do not work please update your question and show your modified UserDAO and your configuration file.

Comment: At last found one solution.Added hibernate-cfg.xml and then used buildSessionFactory to get the session.My revised code is as follows.
 sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();sessionFactory.getCurrentSession